# BufferBlock.ReceiveAsync hangs in a HostedService

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await

I'm trying to use an `IHostedService` as a fire-and-forget email sender in an ASP.NET Core application. It looks like the best way to do this is using the `BufferBlock` class; the trouble is, `ReceiveAsync` never finishes, even when I post new items into the `BufferBlock`.

Here is the `HostedService` base class:

```
public abstract class HostedService
{
    private Task _executingTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_cts.Token);
        return _executingTask.IsCompleted ? _executingTask : Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _cts.Cancel();
        await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

from which my `EmailService` is derived as follows:

```
public sealed class EmailService : HostedService, IEmailService
{
    private readonly ISendEmail _emailClient;
    private readonly BufferBlock<MailMessage> _emailQueue;

    public EmailService(ISendEmail emailClient)
    {
        _emailClient = emailClient;
        _emailQueue = new BufferBlock<MailMessage>();
    }

    public void EnqueueEmail(MailMessage email)
    {
        var accepted = _emailQueue.Post(email);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var nextEmail = await _emailQueue.ReceiveAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await _emailClient.SendMailAsync(nextEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

The `IEmailService` interface is just a simple fire-and-forget method:

```
public interface IEmailService : IHostedService
{
    void EnqueueEmail(MailMessage email);
}
```

So this should all be enough. Within my controllers, I should be able to inject an `IEmailService`, and then enqueue messages as required. The problem is that when I run the following test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(2)]
[InlineData(3)]
[InlineData(10)]
public async Task Emails_are_sent_after_they_are_enqueued(int emailCount)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < emailCount; ++i)
    {
        _emailService.EnqueueEmail(new MailMessage());
    }

    await _testEmailClient.WaitForEmailsToBeSentAsync(emailCount);
}
```

the `ReceiveAsync` method never completes. I have tried using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but this seems to have no effect.

Within my tests, the `HostedService` is started by the ASP.NET Core pipeline, and `ExecuteAsync` is entered. I would expect `ReceiveAsync` to complete when an item is available in the `BufferBlock`, but there must be some threading subtlety I'm missing.

Comment: How do you call `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`?

Comment: They're called internally by the ASP.NET Core pipeline. My testing infrastructure sets up a `WebHost` with a `TestServer`, which automatically launches all services deriving from `IHostedService`.

Comment: I've found out what's going on. I've got two different instances of `EmailService` kicking around, even though I've registered `IEmailService` as a singleton.

Comment: Why are you using a `BufferBlock<T>` instead of an `ActionBlock<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my IoC container was wiring up multiple instances of `IEmailService`, and the instance that was calling `ReceiveAsync` was different to the instance that was calling `Post`. This is because `EmailService` was an instance both of `IEmailService` and `IHostedService`.

The answer was to ditch `IEmailService` altogether. To use `EmailService` in production code, I can inject an `IEnumerable<IHostedService>` instance, then pull my `EmailService` from that collection using `OfType<EmailService>().First()`.